# 40 kHz Emitter Frequency Response

Tags: proximity-sensor, ultrasound, emitter

I've recently purchased [40 kHz transceivers](https://www.newark.com/multicomp/mcusd16p40b12ro/transceiver-40khz-16mm-plastic/dp/17X2012?gross_price=true&CATCI=pla-162181467381&CAAGID=20376569061&CMP=KNC-GUSA-GEN-SHOPPING&CAGPSPN=pla&gclid=Cj0KCQjwguDeBRDCARIsAGxuU8amQiSJBk2SA0-RnCoDE6R3GzkWFbD09Q2jO5aqWRNzoa4uVomRxswaAr9tEALw_wcB&CAWELAID=120185550003030152) and I tested its frequency response in anechoic chamber using a B&K microphone located 90cm away from the emitter. The response provided in the datasheet is

[image]

whereas my finding is

[image]

[image]

What can be causing this discrepancy? The center frequency is clearly not 40 kHz as it was claimed to be.

Is a standing wave causing the notch that is at ~38 kHz?

*I am pretty sure the experiment setup is functioning well.*

Comment: The scale on the first graph is suspect. Why is the 2 kHz from 38 to 40 kHz narrower than 2 kHz from 43 to 45 kHz?

Comment: It would also be easier to compare your result if you plotted it on the same scales: 35 to 48 kHz on the x-axis, and dB scale on the y-axis.

Comment: It appears that the first graph is in dB. The second graph is labelled "amplitude." If you convert the second graph to dB, maybe it will match the first one?

Comment: what impedance were you driving the transducer with. What impedance does tyeh data sheet say to drive it with?

Comment: Normally, in order to have a standing wave, you would have to be in a room that can produce echoes. Also, the wavelength at 38 kHz is less than 1cm. Are you calibrating out the frequency response of the microphone? Could it have a null at 38 kHz?

Comment: Eyeballing it from the graph, it seems like the 3dB bandwidth may be about the same in both graphs. But that doesn't explain the notch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linear Vs Db scale thing accounts for much of this, and these are not exactly precision devices so the centre frequency being slightly off is not a huge surprise.

The notch is only about 3dB, and may well be two transducer modes being excited, you may also be seeing a null due to a reflection from the housing or something, try rotating the transducer very slightly off axis and see if the notch moves.

If reflections causing standing waves are a concern, you can try setting up a time gate on your measurement (Emit a pulse, gate the measurement for when you expect the signal to arrive).